# Rendering nested HAML templates with blocks as parameters

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

I am currently using an helper method to render a HAML nested partial/template in Sinatra. For the sake of simplicity I just wrote a minimal example but of course my code is much larger. The point is that I want to factorise `inner_template` instead of copy/pasting everywhere:

```ruby
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

helpers do
  def inner_template(&block)
    haml_tag('div', :class => 'title', &block)
  end
end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

__END__

@@ layout
%html
  = yield

@@ index
%div.div1
  - inner_template do
    %span Item 1
  - inner_template do
    %span Item 2
```

This correctly renders the page like this:

```html
<html>
  <div class='div1'>
    <div class='title'>
      <span>Item 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class='title'>
      <span>Item 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

The problem is that my real life `inner_template` method has a consequent number of tags, and I find it quite inelegant (and cumbersome when I must edit it). I also want to keep all the inner-most blocks (my items) on the same page, otherwise I'll end up with dozens of small files and it will be a headache to maintain that.

I am under the impression that, since I can use an helper method which only uses `haml_tag` methods, there must be a way to make everything work in pure HAML. But I cannot figure out how to do it properly. For instance if I just try the obvious way:

```ruby
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

__END__

@@ layout
%html
  = yield

@@ index
%div.div1
  = haml :inner_template do
    %span Item 1
  = haml :inner_template do
    %span Item 2

@@ inner_template
%div.title
  = yield
```

This doesn't work, the inner_template is rendered after its "inner" block (as to what exactly yields the value 1, I do not know):

```html
<html>
  <div class='div1'>
      <span>Item 1</span>
  <div class='title'>
      1
    </div>
      <span>Item 2</span>
  <div class='title'>
      1
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

I tried a very long list of hacks, I also tried to use `content_for` or similar solutions (which only seem to apply to old versions of Sinatra anyway), but I cannot find examples that match my approach (which could be a hint that it's just not possible). And it looks like the block is not passed at all to the HAML renderer when calling `haml`.

So I would like to know whether or not this can be done in pure HAML (and how, or why not)?

Comment: Use Sinatra Partial? https://github.com/yb66/Sinatra-Partial

Comment: @iain unfortunately this one didn't work either, when I try to adapt my code to call `partial` rather than `haml`, I end with a `LocalJumpError - no block given (yield)`. It looks like, whatever I try, the inner block (containing the `%span`s) is never transmitted correctly. But I'm clueless as to where it fails, or why.

Comment: Is it that you want to be able to pass contents *dynamically* to `inner_block`, or is this just the strategy you've taken to try to get nested partials to work?

Comment: @iain sorry for the late reply, yes I want to pass contents dynamically, as I'm calling my real life `inner_template` with some parameters such as the contents of the header, and the block itself is a parameter. Please note that the block will display values defined in the route.

Comment: No problem. Maybe it's because you've simplified the code in the question to help clarify, but I'm not really seeing what you're aiming for or why it will improve what you've got?